# Elasticsearch word_delimiter_graph split token on specific delimiter only

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to use an Elasticsearch's Token filter that act like [word_delimiter_graph](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-graph-tokenfilter.html) but split tokens on specific delimiter only (if I am not wrong, default `word_delimiter_graph` does not allow to use custom delimiters list).

For example, I only want to split tokens on `-` delimiter only:

`i-pod` -> `[i-pod, i, pod]`

`i_pod` -> `[i_pod]` (since I only want to split on `-` only and not any other characters.)

How can I archive that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some parameter type_table.

```
(Optional, array of strings) Array of custom type mappings for characters. This allows you to map non-alphanumeric characters as numeric or alphanumeric to avoid splitting on those characters.

For example, the following array maps the plus (+) and hyphen (-) characters as alphanumeric, which means they won’t be treated as delimiters.
```

Tests:

i-pad

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": {
    "type": "word_delimiter_graph",
    "preserve_original": true,
    "type_table": [ "_ => ALPHA" ]
  },
  "text": "i-pad"
}
```

Tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "i-pad",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0,
      "positionLength": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "pad",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

i_pad

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": {
    "type": "word_delimiter_graph",
    "preserve_original": true,
    "type_table": [ "_ => ALPHA" ]
  },
  "text": "i_pad"
}
```

Tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "i_pad",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But I don't want to use `type_table` or `type_table_path` because it need to add so much characters to this list. And this list may be very big, so I don't think it is a good way to solve my problem.

Comment: the only delimiter is "-"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Or maybe other character that I can config later.

Comment: If you want to use a delimiter filter, word_delimiter will solve your problem. The example I made is exactly what you need. If you want to use more delimiters, just add them to the type_table array.
There is no other filter that will do exactly what you need.
You can see the token pattern but it will not preserve the original token.